# VB.Net Ms Access Database. How can I display next value of a row to a lable one by one?

Tags: database, ms-access-2010, vb.net-2010, ms-access-2013

I'm looking for a way to set the next value of a row into a label
without using a Binding Navigator. ex: when I click the *next* button the next username in the username column should appear on the label and keep rolling the names.

- Actually planing to make a quiz so I want to 'roll' the question.

**What I've tried**

I have bound data(ex: usernames) to a label using its property (Data Bindings). Now how can I display them in the label and with each button press have the next one appear?

Comment: I have bounded data(ex: usernames) to a label using its property (Data Bindings). Now how can I display them in the label and with each button next one appear

Comment: please read [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and edit your question to improve your question.

Answer (score 0):

OK, this is what did to achieve that on alternative way:
 but this not working

I'm getting this error >> Syntax error in string in query expression 'tagno='2'. @ line    dr = Command.ExecuteReader

The objective is to on button click the count integer will increment and then the query will use count value to find question from database
for example if the increment value is 2 then the reader should return question from row where tagno two is.

the database table (quest) has following columns, Question Correct_Answer, tagno

```
Dim count As Integer
Private Sub btncontinue_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btncontinue.Click
    Dim conn As New OleDb.OleDbConnection
    Dim olequery As New OleDb.OleDbCommand
    Dim connString As String
    connString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=\" & Application.StartupPath & "\game.accdb"
    conn.ConnectionString = connString
    olequery.Connection = conn
    count += 1
    Dim dr As OleDbDataReader
```

'quest is the table name.
        Dim query As String = "select question from quest where tagno='" & count & ""

```
    cnnOLEDB.Open()
    Dim command As New OleDbCommand(query, cnnOLEDB)
    dr = Command.ExecuteReader
    dr.Read()
    lblquestion.Text = dr(0)
  cnnOLEDB.Close()
End Sub
```